# SQL's Query adding values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I hope you can help me, in this sql query. (SQL SERVER)
I have these tables

```
TABLE1
COLUMN0 COLUMN1 COLUMN2 COLUMN3
A        DOLAR    2.5   18/02/2013
A        DOLAR    1.5   18/02/2013
B        EURO     22    19/02/2013
B        DOLAR    4.5   19/02/2013
B        DOLAR    1.3   18/02/2013
C        EURO     0.5   19/02/2013

TAB_RATES
COLUMN0    COLUMN1
18/02/2013 1.35
19/02/2013 1.36
```

I want to add all the 'B' values (COLUMN2) in dollars
But i have some that are in euros
Column3 in TABLE1 shows dolar value in that date (FK_TAB_RATES)

What would be the sql query?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do?  Just add if `COLUMN1` has a value of `DOLAR` and `COLUMN0` has a value of `B`?  Or are you trying to convert euro's or something?

Comment: This question is *very* difficult to understand.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is your Tab_Rates table is the currency multiplier for that given day.  If so, something like this might work:

```
SELECT SUM (T.Column2 *
    CASE 
        WHEN T.Column1 = 'Euro'
        THEN TR.Column1
        ELSE 1.0
    END) SummedAmt
FROM Table1 T
    JOIN Tab_Rates TR ON T.Column3 = TR.Column0
WHERE T.Column0 = 'B'
```

And here is a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8d192/1) to demo it.

This produces 35.72.  Doing it manually, 4.5 + 1.3 + 22(1.36) = 35.72

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this (untested)

```
select t1.col0,
    sum (case when t1.col1 = 'euro' then t1.col1 * rate.r
              else t1.col1 end) as s
from t1
inner join rate on rate.r = t1.col3
group by col0
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT SUM (T.Column2 *
    CASE 
        WHEN T.Column1 = 'Euro'
        THEN TR.Column1
        ELSE 1.0
    END) SummedAmt
FROM Table1 T
    JOIN Tab_Rates TR ON T.Column3 = TR.Column0
WHERE T.Column0 = 'B'
```